# How can I make a batch file that opens a program if a user closed it?

Tags: batch-file

I got this right now:

```
@echo off
:Start
start /w run.exe
goto start
```

I want that it don't ask you something when you close the program `run.exe`.

Comment: What is the issue with the code you've got?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit start /w

```
@echo off
:Start
run.exe
goto Start
```

Comment: then it just opens the run.exe in the batch itself i want that it opens a new window with the exe in it and if i close the exe that it startup again automatic

Comment: run.exe is a console application?

Then start /w is correct if you want to have an extra console. There are issues with omitting the title, though. Better use

    start /w "" run.exe

Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: for what stands the "" and i want that if i open that bat that it opens the program not in the batch itself but in a new window and if i close that new window then the batch reopens it again